# How to make discord bot leave server just after joining

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a command that makes the bot leave a server, but, they can make the bot rejoin which i don't want and i also don't want to enable code grant as i want other servers to use my bot. and i have to keep on resting the script each time the bot joins a server i want the bot to leave just after it joins after all there isn't a way to ban it from the server. So here is my script.

```
@client.event
    async def on_ready():
        my_server = client.get_server('520354830472970270')
        await client.leave_server(my_server)
        print('left server')`
```

Comment: Have you tried to "blacklist" them on your side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the bot leave the server immediately after it joins by using the [`on_server_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_server_join) event.

```
@client.event
async def on_server_join(server):
    if server.id == "id":
        await client.leave_server(server)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.event
async def on_server_join(server):
    """So we basically check if the server id equals the id you've sent, and you want it to leave exactly after it joined to that server."""
    if server.id not != "520354830472970270": # We're checking if the ID is not unequal to 520354830472970270
        await client.leave_server(server) # The server parameter of this event returns us a server object, so we don't have to get it separately.
```